# Unable to connect to monero-wallet-rpc from code

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, javascript

I have run the monero-wallet-rpc using the below command:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 8080--rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --prompt-for-password --wallet-file sample-wallet --rpc-login walletuser:user1234 --confirm-external-bind
```

When I do the below curl command, it's working fine.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_address","params":{"account_index":0,"address_index":[0,1,4]}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u walletuser:user1234 --digest
```

But when I try to call the RPC from the below javascript code, I am getting `401 Unauthorized` error.

```
var digestRequest  = require('request-digest')('walletuser', 'user1234');
digestRequest.requestAsync({
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  path: '/json_rpc',
  port: 8080,
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  body: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_address","params":{"account_index":0,"address_index":[0,1,4]}},
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use digest authentication in your javascript but the wallet RPC uses basic authorization.